# Is concern about employee retention mostly for show?

Tags: management

It seems as though if hiring were as costly as companies claimed and retaining knowledge mattered all that much then turnover wouldn't be high.

Everyone knows why people are quitting in tech. It is because the best way to get ahead is to leave. There is no secret to it but the industry collectively shrugs and is fine with the churn.

Should 1 on 1s and employee surveys be treated as attempts to scam employees?

Comment: I'm sorry, but the word "scam" is just the completely wrong word for this phenomenon. Should bumping my salary in an attempt to retain me, be regarded as a "scam" too? And if it is a "scam", what should I do -- call the police?

Comment: There is a difference between acknowledging that a thing would be good and valuable and actually doing the thing. Ask anyone with an active gym subscription but 0 hours logged :)

Comment: What do you mean by 1 on 1s and employee surveys?

Comment: Why do you think that 1 on 1s and employee surveys might be scams? That doesn't seem to follow from the rest of your post.

Comment: My guess is that it is the idea that 1-on-1s and employee-surveys all turn up the idea that people are unhappy because they can't get ahead without leaving, but tech firms don't actually act on this

Comment: Don't understand the question or where the idea of "scam" comes from... but something important to note is: to a business, Value For Money is important.

Comment: "Not genuine or sincere" is probably a better way to describe this than "scam".

Comment: The answer is simply "YES".  Sure "scam" may not be the perfect word in English, but it's perfectly clear what the OP means.  And the OP is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This would be locale specific, and perhaps industry specific. I view it as more of a developer phenomena.

Engineers don't have a huge turnover except for incompetent ones. They're just as much tech as developers.

Locale specific because many locales do not have a lot of dev work, so developers can't just move on whenever they want and the ones that start hopping end up with nothing pretty quickly.

Companies tend to have set protocols for employees and treat developers the same as everyone else. So it's not a scam per se, just treating devs like any other employees in a professional capacity.

At the end of the day you get out of it what you put in. If you go in thinking about scams, you won't come out with much of anything.